# pong game godot reset the scene

Tags: game-development, godot

hello I am currently working on my first game in godot. It is a pong replica with power ups I am currently having difficulty resetting the scene when the score that is specified is reached.
This is my code:

```
if(PlayerSore == 10 || OpponentScore == 10):
    get_tree().paused = true
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_reset"):
        get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

this is all happening in the `func _process(delta):` function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the `get_tree().paused = true`. If the node that that script is on has its `pause_mode` set to inherit or stop then `_process` probably won't be called (see [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-property-pause-mode) for more info). I would recommend just deleting that line unless there is a specific reason you need it.